# roboearth compile fails

Tags: roboearth, ubuntu, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I've tried to test the brandnew roboearth, but the compile fails at re_vision...

INFO:
UBUNTU 10.10
ROS electric

```
  make[3]: Betrete Verzeichnis '/home/ros/prog/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_vision/build'
  [ 19%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/DUtilsCV.dir/src/3rdparty/DUtilsCV/Drawing.o
  /home/ros/prog/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_vision/src/3rdparty/DUtilsCV/Drawing.cpp: In static member function ‘static void DUtilsCV::Drawing::drawCorrespondences(cv::Mat&, const cv::Mat&, const cv::Mat&, const std::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> >&, const std::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> >&, const std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, const std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&)’:
  /home/ros/prog/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_vision/src/3rdparty/DUtilsCV/Drawing.cpp:107: error: no matching function for call to ‘cv::Mat::setTo(CvScalar)’
  /usr/include/opencv-2.3.1/opencv2/core/core.hpp:1662: note: candidates are: cv::Mat& cv::Mat::setTo(const cv::_InputArray&, const cv::_InputArray&)
  /home/ros/prog/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_vision/src/3rdparty/DUtilsCV/Drawing.cpp:108: warning: taking address of temporary
  /home/ros/prog/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_vision/src/3rdparty/DUtilsCV/Drawing.cpp:117: warning: taking address of temporary
  /home/ros/prog/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_vision/src/3rdparty/DUtilsCV/Drawing.cpp:125: warning: taking address of temporary
  make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/DUtilsCV.dir/src/3rdparty/DUtilsCV/Drawing.o] Fehler 1
  make[3]: Verlasse Verzeichnis '/home/ros/prog/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_vision/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/DUtilsCV.dir/all] Fehler 2
  make[2]: Verlasse Verzeichnis '/home/ros/prog/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_vision/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Fehler 2
  make[1]: Verlasse Verzeichnis '/home/ros/prog/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_vision/build'
```

Thanks for any help
Christian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11168/roboearth-compile-fails/) by [Chrimo](https://answers.ros.org/users/361/chrimo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 390 on 2011-09-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Christian,

currently, the RoboEarth packages are only useable under ROS Diamondback.
We are working on porting them to ROS Electric, though.

Cheers,
Daniel

---

Originally posted by [ddimarco](https://answers.ros.org/users/1073/ddimarco/) with karma: 916 on 2011-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3